# How to disable / use Visual Studio's title bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to use the space wasted by Visual Studio 2010's title bar.

Is it possible to put the toolbar or the tab bar in the title bar, like Google Chrome?

Can it be done writing an extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to not be possible, even with Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio has a full screen mode:  View -> Full Screen Mode (or Shift + Alt + Enter, by default).

Comment: If I enable Full Screen Mode i loose the toolbar and the windows start menu task bar.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible, at least in VS2013 (but will probably work also with other versions supported by VisualCommander extension). Here is the needed macro, maybe someone will find it useful:

> 4. Hide title bar in Visual Studio 2013.

```
public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        events = DTE.Events;
        dteEvents = events.DTEEvents;
        dteEvents.OnStartupComplete += OnStartupComplete;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        dteEvents.OnStartupComplete -= OnStartupComplete;
    }
    private void OnStartupComplete()
    {
        try
        {
            HideTitleBar();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    private bool HideTitleBar()
    {
        System.Windows.FrameworkElement e = 
            FindElement(System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow, 
                "MainWindowTitleBar");
        if (e != null)
        {
            e.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private System.Windows.FrameworkElement FindElement(System.Windows.Media.Visual v, string name)
    {
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(v); ++i)
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Visual child = 
                System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(v, i) as
                    System.Windows.Media.Visual;
            if (child != null)
            {
                System.Windows.FrameworkElement e = 
                    child as System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
                if (e != null && e.Name == name)
                    return e;
            }
            System.Windows.FrameworkElement result = FindElement(child, name);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private EnvDTE.Events events;
    private EnvDTE.DTEEvents dteEvents;
}
```

Source: https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html